# Dart import local package does not bring classes

Tags: dart

I'm new to [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart) and just learning it. One of my first project is right here in Github:

[DartSimpleChat](https://github.com/jasper22/DartSimpleChat)

It's very easy client/server app build when reading various tutorials. Actually it contains 3 project: Server, Client and Shared.

- Server (console application) open `WebSocket` and for now just listening for incoming messages.
- Client (HTML app) open `WebSocket` and send `SimpleChatMessage` converted to `Json` string.
- Shared is project-container for `SimpleChatMessage` class definition.

  Both project (Client and Server) must include the `Shared` project to correctly use `SimpleChatMessage` class. I followed the specs on [pub.dartlang](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages) site and I see that Shared project correctly listed in list of all packages.

  The problem is that Shared project strangely does not bring any classes with it. It just sits there empty.

  Here is the screenshot:

  [image: Empty package]

  Inside the Client project the `import` directive working like this:

  ```
  import 'package:DartSimpleChat_Shared/SimpleChatShared.dart';
  ```

  What I'm doing wrong ? And why my local package does not bring actual classes with it ?

  I'm using:

  - Dart Editor version 0.4.3_r20602
  - Dart SDK version 0.4.3.5_r20602
  - Ubuntu 12.10 x64

Comment: Could you paste your `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin there's actually on GitHub but if can not reach there here is copy on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xTUxbdQ4)

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that editor is not showing files for path dependencies. Once `pub install` done, your project seems not to have errors (except the mix between `SimpleChatMessage` and `SimpleMessage`).

Comment: So it just Dart Editor bug ?

Comment: bug or feature, I don't know.

Comment: I had a similar issue with VSCode where a project i had cloned did not recognize the local packages. The fix was to ensure the right environment was mentioned in pubspec.yaml. The original project had an older sdk.